# Bubble Sort Optimization C++

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I was just practising a little bit and tried to sort an array with the bubble sort algorithm.
Compiler didn't give me any warnings nor errors and it worked well! First you type 10 times a number and then the program sorts them + prints them.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void arr_sort(int* array, const int arr_size){

int temp = 0;   //Temporary integer to store (if necessary) the current element
int end = 0;    //Run time condition

while(end++ != arr_size){ // Will loop max. 10 times

    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){

        if(array[i] > array[i + 1]){    //If the current element 
            temp = array[i];    //is bigger than the next

            array[i] = array[i + 1];//Change the positions
            array[i + 1] = temp;    
        }
    }
}

}

int main(){

int arr_input[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)      //The user has to type 10 numbers
    cin >> arr_input[i];        //which will be stored in this array

arr_sort(arr_input, 10);        //sorts the array

cout << endl << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)     //Print out the array!
    cout << arr_input[i] << ", ";
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

My only problem is the while-loop in the arr_sort function. I mean it sorts the array until **end** has the same value as **arr_size**. But often it doesn't need that long. My question now... How can I improve this function? How can I test if the array is completely sorted so the while-loop can stop without running another time and another time ...?

Comment: Just outside of the for loop, place a bool and set it to false. Inside the swap block, set the bool to true. After the for loop, check the value of the boolean, and if it's still false, no swaps were made so the array is sorted, so break out of the while loop.

Comment: @alex23 Considering the question asked, your comment is pointlessly off-topic. Save random thoughts for discussion forums, would you. Or, post complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just outside of the for loop, place a bool and set it to false. Inside the swap block, set the bool to true. After the for loop, check the value of the boolean, and if it's still false, no swaps were made so the array is sorted, so break out of the while loop.

```
while(end++ != arr_size){ // Will loop max. 10 times

    bool swapped = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){

        if(array[i] > array[i + 1]){    //If the current element 
            temp = array[i];    //is bigger than the next

            array[i] = array[i + 1];//Change the positions
            array[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped = true;    
        }
    }
    if (!swapped) break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Before your `for` loop, assume it's sorted:

```
bool sorted = true;
```

In your `if` statement`, record that it's not sorted:

```
sorted = false;
```

After your `for` loop`, return if there was no evidence that it's not sorted:

```
if ( sorted ) return;
```

Comment: I like this. I've always done it with the boolean starting as false, but your way is actually slightly more intuitive